# Regular Expression to match relative URLs - II

Tags: regex, whitespace

Continue with the previous question,

[Regular Expression to match relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447131/regular-expression-to-match-relative-urls)

we are facing a slight problem with space in the relative Urls. Lets say, we have two scenarios:

/abc/part%20Red/

/abc/part Red/

First relative URl is retrived but second relative URL returned **/abc/part** instead of **/abc/part Red/**

We cann't add \s in our allowed character list. If we add \s in the allowed character list, we may get more wrong Urls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that spaces are not allowed in URLs, only %20.  It is impossible to tell whether text after a space is part of the URL or not.  Take the following example:

```
Go to /user/docs/document and look in sections 3/5
```

```
Go to /user/docs/document with spaces and look in sections 3/5
```

There is no way to programmatically tell which words are part of the URL and which are just words.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not able to get your example. Can you please explain.

Comment: I assume you are trying to parse URLs out of text, so I gave some examples of URLs surrounded by text.

In the first one, the URL is `/user/docs/document` while in the second one, it is `/user/docs/document with spaces`.  However, there is no way to tell this from looking at it.